# Lambda Authorizer of type Request not working in Kotlin

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, custom-authentication, lambda-authorizer

I've been trying to use a custom authorizer ( lambda authorizer ) of type Request for a certain HTTP API in Kotlin.

Taking inspiration from [this](https://www.kabisa.nl/tech/enriching-requests-with-an-aws-lambda-authorizer/), I wrote the following :

```
class AuthorizerHandler : RequestHandler<Map<String, Any>, AuthorizerResponse>{


    override fun handleRequest(input: Map<String, Any>, context: Context?): AuthorizerResponse {

        val LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AuthorizerHandler::class.java)

        LOG.info(input)
        
        val headers = input["headers"]!! as Map<*, *>

        val authorization = headers["authorization"]!! as String

        val arn  = input["routeArn"]!! as String

        val tokenBody: TokenBody = TokenBody.fromToken(authorization)

        LOG.info("SUB : ${tokenBody.userID}")

        val proxyContext = input["requestContext"] as Map<*, *>
        val principalId  = proxyContext["accountId"] as String
        

        val statement = IamPolicyResponse.Statement.builder().withResource(listOf("*"))
            .withEffect("Allow")
            .withAction("execute-api:Invoke")
            .build()

        

        val policyDocument = IamPolicyResponse.PolicyDocument.builder()
            .withStatement(listOf(statement))
            .withVersion("2012-10-17")
            .build()

       
        return AuthorizerResponse(principalId = tokenBody.userID, policyDocument = policyDocument)


      
    }
}
```

`TokenBody` is custom class with init function `fromToken` that helps me deconstruct the token. It's working as expected and `tokenBody.userID` gives me the user's `sub`.

`AuthorizerResponse` is also a custom class which looks like this :

```
class AuthorizerResponse (
    @JsonProperty("principalId")
    val principalId: String? = null,

    @JsonProperty("policyDocument")
    val policyDocument: IamPolicyResponse.PolicyDocument? = null,

    @JsonProperty("context")
    val context: Map<String, String>? = null,
)
```

First I was supplying `arn` as the Resource when building my statement. Calling the API resulted in

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Changing Resource to `*` doesn't help either and throws the same 500 Internal Server Error.

Similarly, I've tried accountID as principalID as well but that doesn't work either.

I've checked the logs of the Authorizer lambda but that doesn't throw any error so it's technically working as expected after getting invoked properly.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Edit : Mentioned the type of API.

Comment: Adding `enableSimpleResponses: true` in my authorizer config enables me to send a boolean which acts as a reasonable workaround in my case. Now I send return `mapOf("isAuthorized" to  true)` which allows the user to access the HTTP API.